# How to rotate a li using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for grammar mistakes. I'm unable to ask question properly so that's why I'm using image for understanding my problem. I have three `LI`  in circle and I want to make a function which  will able to

- Onclick `li` will rotate and stop against orange box and change the other two position.
- Other two `li` will also work similarly

### Note:

Li is basically showing its div onclick. Please help me

[image]

Here is my [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/y74ty/)

### CSS

```
ul{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5%
    }
ul li{
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    padding:5%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    }
ul li div{
  display:none;
}
.skill-box{
    width:500px;
    height:70px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    left:20%;
    position:absolute;}
```

### HTML

```
<ul id="circle">
        <li>
            <div class="pie"></div>
            one <div class="skill-box">Skill Box 1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            two <div class="skill-box">Skill Box 2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Three <div class="skill-box">Skill Box 3</div>  
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is **JavaScript** for showing li boxes.

```
<script>  
    $("li").click(function(){   
        $("li div").not($("div",$(this))).hide();   
        $("div",$(this)).fadeToggle("fast");
         }) 

</script>
```

Comment: I've put the image in the post for you, but you should probably include your code in the post too, rather than just linking to JSFiddle.

Comment: That said, you don't appear to have tried anything to solve this problem...

Comment: Stop coding, turn on Wheel of Fortune on the telly, see the wheel spin, be happy, problem solved... next !

Comment: SDD - Stackoverflow Driven Development. :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have added my code.

Comment: @user3659202 Thank you - however as I said your code appears to contain no attempt at actually solving the problem ;)

Comment: I have to try to make it but failed and i'm new in development so can any one make it for me please

Comment: If you're new to development, how will you learn how to code if we make it completely for you? Also, if you're new to development, you should start with something easy, like a hello world program, instead of a jump into the deep with something as complicated as a roulette wheel. Learn to swim in the kiddy pool, don't jump into the deep end of the wave pool on your first day.

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to build is a roulette wheel, basically.

Some simple googling has found me this site:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

You'll need a htlm5 canvas element. this won't work if you need to support certain older versions of IE. It's a lot of code to hotlink here, so I'll refer you to the website. Should it ever go unavailable. i'm sure [googling for Javascript roulette wheel](https://www.google.be/search?q=javascript%20roulette%20wheel&oq=javascript%20roulette%20wheel&aqs=chrome..69i57.4024j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) will get you somewhere.

edit: the HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="spin" style="float:left;" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

The javascript for generating the wheel:

```
var colors = ["#B8D430", "#3AB745", "#029990", "#3501CB",
             "#2E2C75", "#673A7E", "#CC0071", "#F80120",
             "#F35B20", "#FB9A00", "#FFCC00", "#FEF200"];
var restaraunts = ["Wendy's", "McDonalds", "Chick-fil-a", "Five Guys",
                   "Gold Star", "La Mexicana", "Chipotle", "Tazza Mia",
                   "Panera", "Just Crepes", "Arby's", "Indian"];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 6;
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;

var ctx;

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 200;
    var textRadius = 160;
    var insideRadius = 125;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);


    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = restaraunts[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    } 

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
  var text = restaraunts[index]
  ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t/=d)*t;
  var tc = ts*t;
  return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have updated the original answer with the Javascript and HTML. However, it wasn't so much my intent to answer this question as it was to subtly imply that he should have searched on Google first before asking us to basically write his program for him.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Thanks for updating your answer. However, with an implication like that, you probably should have commented with those links ;)

Comment: I guess that might have been the better option. I'm still trying to figure out when to post an answer and when to post a comment. I always thought: if you're asking for information, post a comment. if you're providing a solution or attempted solution, post an answer.